# Hard drive works inconsistently on internal system connection

Tags: hard-drive, desktop

My secondary drive—a 1TB WD Caviar Blue—is not being recognised neither by windows nor in BIOS. I am running Windows 8.1 on a system with an i5 CPU, 16GB of RAM and I tried cleaning and reinserting all of the components of course before anything else.

Here's where it gets weird

- Doesn't make any weird, unusual noises (doesn't click like its head is stuck or smthn), it does make the usual power up sound
- Tried using the drive in an Icy Box (external hard drive enclosure ) and then connected it, via USB 3.0 to the same PC and it works fine, tested it for several hours.
- Tried 2 different 1TB hard disk drives on the same PC. On the same connections, with the same cables etc as the faulty one, they worked just fine.
- Tried the drive again on the PC, worked for a day, then the same problem occurred. Immediately repeated the steps above, same results as before.

So, I'm a bit confused as to which component failed. The drive seems to be working fine by its own, so are the cables and the rest of my setup.

Is there anything else I can check or do, before I blindly start buying parts that may or may not solve the problem?

Comment: You most likely have an intermittent issue you haven’t discovered yet. Like a bad power connection, or bad port on the hard drive. You usually find bad connections by wiggling wires around while you run some kind of continuous test. Like copying a large file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possiblities:

- **The drive and cable just don't like each other.**  It's weird when this happens and defies explanation, but it's true.  Sometimes a particular device and a particular cable just don't get along with each other. Tiny variations in wire tension, contact pad height, springiness of the connectors, etc. can all conspire to create a poor connection.  Fortunately, this is easy to fix; all you have to do is use a different cable.  If you don't have a spare cable, try swapping it with the cable connected to your other drive.  Also try connecting it to a different SATA port on the motherboard.  Your OS drive is a known good port, so try swapping that one also. The OS won't mind being connected to a different port most of the time.
- **The drive might not be receiving enough power.**  This one is difficult to diagnose unless this is a custom build and you've hand-picked a power supply that you know for certain is big enough.  Branded PCs like Dell and HP tend to size their power supplies very conservatively because it's cheaper for them, but it might not be able to deliver enough power if you've added lots of aftermarket devices.  Additionally, there are multiple voltage rails, so its possible to overload one rail but still be entirely within the PSU's power envelope.  The easiest way to verify this is to remove your video card and use the onboard video if this is an option for you. Video cards are very power hungry, so if you're having a power issue, removing the video card will probably resolve it.  Of course, this would mean you'll need a bigger power supply if it does.  You could also try to plug the drive into a different strand from the PSU. Different strands are often wired to different power rails.
- **The drive or cable might be receiving interference from nearby devices.**  This one is a toughie and pretty rare, but I've seen it happen.  If the cable itself is laying against some capacitors or curled around other components (particularly WiFi/Bluetooth cards), this can be an issue.  The only real way to verify this is to read the SMART data off the drive using a tool that can let you see this information.  If you see a lot of error-correction happening, this is a very good indicator that interference is your problem. Using short, high-quality cables is your only real fix here.

That's about all I can think of.  I would say check the BIOS to see if there are any power management or HDD-specific settings in there but you said the BIOS doesn't even see it. So that points to a power/SATA issue to me.